# Function to find min and max values in a vector, and returning their indexes

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ I just started learning it this week.

As stated in the question, I am trying to find the highest and lowest value in the vector `vector<int> pricelist{10,23,45,12,32}`so I expect to get a return of 0 and 2.

```
public:
Prices(const int lowestPriceIn, const int highestPriceIn)
       : lowestPrice(lowestPriceIn), highestPrice(highestPriceIn) {
   }
```

I want to put a function in a method `lowestNHighestPrices()`.

I am assuming I can create a loop that iterates through the vector, but how would I determine which would be the lowest and highest value? And how would I get just the indexes and not the elements?

I have 2 get methods that return 2 int variables, one for the lowest value and the other for the highest.

```
int getlowestPrice() const {
       return lowestPrice;
   }

   int gethighestPrice() const {
       return highestPrice;
   }
```

Comment: Search for how to get the min/max values in a vector. Then search for how to get an index from an iterator. Both have been asked and answered plenty of times here.

Comment: [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to get both min and max and their respective indices in one go, in the following way:

```
std::vector<int> v {10,23,45,12,32};
auto mm = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
auto idx_min = std::distance(v.begin(), mm.first);
auto idx_max = std::distance(v.begin(), mm.second);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d803bc2fb3d9fa5f)

Comment: I keep getting an error std namespace has no member minmax_element. Why is this the case?

Comment: @LovesPie did you include `<algorithm>` header? Does your compiler supports C++11?

Comment: Sorry not entirely sure what the <algorithm> header is (I did say I am very new to the language).... and yes it does support c++11.

Comment: @LovesPie in the `.cpp` code file that you call `std::minmax_element` do you have `#include <algorithm>`? Cause `std::minmax_element` is defined in that header.

Comment: Oh ok it's not there. I am not sure if I am allowed to alter the .cpp file because it's used to test if my code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getlowestPrice() const {
   vector<int>::iterator it = std::min_element(pricelist);
   lowestPrice = it - pricelist.begin();
   return lowestPrice; 
}

int gethighestPrice() const {
   vector<int>::iterator it = std::max_element(pricelist);
   highestPrice = it - pricelist.begin();
   return highestPrice; 
}
```

Comment: How does `vector<int> iterator it` compile?