# Finding the indexes of the highest and lowest elements from a vector C++

Tags: c++

I know these questions have been answered to death, but I have to perform these under certain restrictions. I am new to C++ and am just doing some exercises in order to get used to the new language.

Firstly I have a `vector<int> pricelist{12,32,43,23,54}` the element values and number of elements, do not matter as it will change depending on the test. It is located in a **Test.cpp** which will check if met the requirements. So in this instance the test would check to see if `price.getlowestPrice == 0`, and `price.gethighestPrice == 4`.

I have header file I need to work with, the code in it consists of,

```
class Prices{
protected:
    int highestPrice;
    int lowestPrice;

public:

Trade(const int highPriceIn, const int lowPriceIn)
    : highestPrice(highPriceIn), lowestPrice(lowPriceIn) {
}

int getllowestPrice() const {
    return lowestPrice;
}

int gethighestPrice() const {
    return highestPrice;
   }

 };
```

I clearly very clueless (as you will soon see) on the syntax of c++ (or coding in general I guess) I tried creating a method to find the min and max and to return the index but I don't know the right way to go about it (did not add a return because I didn't know what to return).

```
int lowNhightPrices(vector<int> prices) {
int min, max;
    max = min = 0;
    int currentState;
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.size(); ++i) {

        {
            if (prices[i] < prices[min])
            {
                min = i;
            }
            else if (prices[i] > prices[max])
            {
                max = i;
            }
```

Comment: What are the restrictions?

Comment: May be something like [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: Basically I can't change anything in the Test.cpp. And I can't seem to use any std:: ehh...stuff?

Comment: Look at [how-to-return-several-values-from-a-function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/how-to-return-several-values-from-a-function#t=201610041934247114657)

Comment: @LovesPie _"And I can't seem to use any std:: ehh...stuff?"_ That leaves you doomed probably.

Comment: (warning nitpicking) the lowest and highest index of a vector are 0 and size-1, respectively

Comment: @tobi303 oh...ok ehh I think I mean't to say the highest and lowest elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to find min and max values in a vector, and returning their indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846725/function-to-find-min-and-max-values-in-a-vector-and-returning-their-indexes)

Comment: @LocaVolatility I was the one that asked that question...because I wasn't getting the right answer and no matter how much I try editing the question I would not get any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

`lowNhightPrices` can return the either the indices of minimum and maximum values, or the minimum and maximum values themselves. Either way, you can use `std::pair<int, int>` as the return type.

```
std::pair<int, int> lowNhightPrices(vector<int> const& prices) {
   ...
   // Return the values.
   // return {minValue, maxValue};

   // Or, return the indices.
   return {minIndex, maxIndex};
}
```

Comment: Just a question...is my loop to search for the min/max values correct? Or is it completely wrong?